# Create irreversible exe file from python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have some python scripts that I have converted to .exe file using `pyinstaller`.

Today I have discovered that some tools can do the opposite, take my .exe file and covert it back to .py.

My question is:
Is there a way to make an .exe file from .py script, that people **won’t** be able to convert back to .py?

Comment: You understand that any executable can be "understood" by a determined enough engineer.

Comment: Afaik not with regular python. You could try Cython which turns it into bytecode which is harder to reverse.

Comment: https://nuitka.net/ is pretty cool.

Comment: "Harder" is not "impossible". _Anything_ can be reverse engineered. That includes programs written in C or even assembly.

Comment: (aside: I happen to be the author of https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/pydeinstaller; that's just a very simple case of slapping glue code together -- for more interesting cases where things were compiled to native executables I'd be pulling out Ghidra)